# Getting Strange Google Analytics URL Data

Tags: wordpress, security, google-analytics

I recently opened up my google analytics and looked at the behavior panel all pages in depth for the first time and I noticed some strange pages such as:

```
/amobee/a3d-ad-loader.html?a3dWebglBanner=https://cdn-production.amobee3d.com/__integration__/9cbea9d/a3d-webgl-banner.js&adName=canon_sp&bucket=cdn-production.amobee3d.com&creativeId=phone&tpt={"tpt-click":"http://r.turn.com/r/tpclick/urlid/14BFxPtiFHxrmUcNdR4QHN-0x-Yel1rNyX3oaT1U1nk4Xtdr-WJQO1XlpD1d2cgzm_yn98_nqu0l-H7-6TDbnFAVUaa81rE5Va5TPoJV_1Ntn4-ZNPeiesLCUWGi5Q0pMIlxWeHujtiWU4hIRmxZhGDbLcisF5vf52pYjnxx7sgLDq60qaLSM9lSDH_P7r3m2LfHLNhuhT3pi82fEsIKY-zMcLaIqUa9FRu7ru1ABYiMCtsmIp-lbv-0tHQ0QtXb2XvAslSEVQju5WCkGeXtYPPWcOXdh4wRx2g-XrBQLJqyt0vA7eW1L6lLODoYREs9OBPuTEypwnf63U3p8t5FBYUJmQbyMz4eKCUfVCW3oZA8XwQsSlpxKWOwnR4ICWD6Hv0vAV2VuhJR0Xs53RIHS3H9Tz63br3HTEa4ZY_kKFET9A_ftQbvMsRO4u41FP6SKbtlYbh9rP6ujKbOzAN8TRFll4D4qUWscfwlVaUN_u2u5E4Vy42t_bSnl21XJcaYEQEFVUTsKZNXtOXj9z5KcYao4xmdD4GUUWyryckAdVyWahvx4V_d16JvQHawx4X3ioQH0_wNdsrb3RVATpziopDFpbZaBPUHiKLZ-bIyufGmXpZmxg-3vX-zu1vvsZPbJNqcc9li1Ympbj3ShiZ1AiIxqUrWzljp1f1In7Z8Im-yg3_KM0J57D8-gUsHIZ-oX3ZGD89yOo93M3XBqtzuW2Hsic-itJBXhnJzspzQ4UqNbGQz9oR24Gk94As9pRznxJBPBDq4ETbqpQBtH7BoKHQ/3c/https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/aclk?sa=l&ai=C4Uxke2G6WaDwNofbpAOzu7eoBf7D7ZRGiM-B9pQBwI23ARABIABgyabejOCk0BSCARdjYS1wdWItODQ0NTQ5NjI3NTYxOTU2N6ABjPe59APIAQmoAwGqBHxP0Hg-A8VrFKLhd4VPGK02nOSLdJlNn7XiRxtz6uzu19NuxGmz5enbVlB2iirq6fTo1Hjk0ggr3O7qFuCqnbrLdm_fi-5tala6iCF3bFK5yG40vufVOofQQ-0YefypkSbFeGdRzK6ke5XOGaI8UaVEAoiTfHwrtnGA6nyzgAbd2MidmYzBhAygBiGoB6a-G9gHANIIBQiAARAB&num=1&sig=AOD64_06gu58j3wZF6kAoqQM6TYyaPYIBQ&client=REMOVED&adurl=/url/"}


/flashtalking/ftlocal.html?ifsrc=https://cdn.flashtalking.com/xre/271/2711110/1979640/js/j-2711110-1979640.js&ftx=&fty=&ftadz=&ftscw=&ft_custom=&ftOBA=1&ft_ifb=1&ft_domain=REMOVEDft_agentEnv=0&ft_referrer=REMOVED&cachebuster=750934.4320502493&click=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/dbm/clk?sa=L&ai=Ce9A4rOjBWbK7BMnWkgP6w6nwB4GMv7JMitPArpwG-7idztoIEAEg0JjELWDJ5v6GgICgGcgBCagDAaoEuAFP0IwsQBfm1IhnAEcv-Kxde6xOfh27RXolPw6jRU8iIA8UyhMCIzdPsjzlztPIEk-d6gwfr438fNB4ptnk2O2-NRq8iKLUF9M4vcKS2aV9IoNcN3v5gcOhtR8Woojv_R8C-z6cDbensRSTTYYVM9RS8OIGbiXrVvsrHcU7kb8vlmMS0EIKD_5NwhCenv4gRE9-_U1Q1r05lJPI1RAJ1m2m_LPSflL_nb5m8BpwYhfJFdBGanLwgh7LwASLsqq1rgHgBAOIBd3Zs7sDkAYBoAZN2AYCgAefycxeqAemvhvYBwCgCP-hpwSwCALSCAcIgGEQARgCyBPg1p0C0BMA2BMDghQTGhF3d3cudm9sdW1lYm90LmNvbQ&num=1&cid=CAASEuRoTBJWebFR9Y_pZL7ze3vdCg&sig=AOD64_2PqRgxPypUSzjJHrRA4kFBwKQPZQ&client=REMOVED&dbm_c=AKAmf-BdHzMrPFTxYQj06utKwilI6E9GHRDztBNwp4NEhB2BuaayZ6JG_BcT226zfnDtdwABfZhe&dbm_d=AKAmf-BWr8_Qqd0y7BMDQPUfEaK5z_iR3KXo8wstJkrl5wytBRYlArCAOqS_TR4m5kPBDNYQmT520pL98pRp6u4h6seeuW53gXANeGvEaPqByEZTbKzlzs7zvX_HqjcevAzg0oDNVrcKyt6jc0SRG5LJGM-YrbtMWCm0-ceIau7y4qp_WK-X5-c&adurl=&ftimpid=35502EEB8067F1&ft_id=&ftcustom=&ftsection=&fttime=1505880237&ftcfid=6825920&ftguid=3165AF587F7584
```

I removed the client value and some other fields and replaced with REMOVED for anonymity purposes but I was wondering if anyone can tell me if it's malware.

I have a site that uses wordpress in the cloud and I have scanned with wordfence saying that my site is clean.

Was wondering if I should look deeper, or if this behavioral page is normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amobee](https://www.amobee.com/) and [Flashtalking](http://www.flashtalking.com/) are both advertising platforms, so it looks somebody has configured advertising tags incorrectly. Probably those clicks should be routed through the respective platforms (e.g. to record data for bid management or something like that) and instead they go directly to your page with redirect Urls appended. If you do paid advertising then you should check with the people who configured this for you.

Comment: okay thank you - i don't do paid advertising but i have adsense on my website. I was worried it was malware but apparently it is benign ~